# If we can seed a torrent, why can't we host a website from our home computer?

Tags: internet, webserver, bittorrent, web-hosting

Seeding a torrent means giving other people access to the files in our computer. Why can't we host a website from our computer?

My service provider is not letting me host a website but they let me seed torrents, how do they do that? How can I host a website?

Comment: You can host a website from your computer?

Comment: How do you know they're not letting you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My service provider is not letting me host a website but they let me seed torrents, how do they do that? How can I host a website?

First, it may be merely against your provider's terms of service to host a website.  So you may not be technically prevented from doing this, but you would violate the TOS if you did so.

A way to technically enforce the above is

- for your ISP to block incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443 to your home IP.  You could still host a website by having your web server listen on an alternate port.  The alternate port would have to be specified in URLs you provide to others.

  - This is the primary way they would prevent you from implementing services that others connect to from outside your home network, blocking incoming traffic by port number.  Most Bittorrent clients use random ports (aside from the trackers) so it's difficult to block traffic (requires DPI) and more difficult if encrypted (requires DPI and MITM).
- for your ISP to implement Carrier Grade NAT (CGN).  This would prevent anyone outside of your ISP's network from initiating a connection to your system, as your ISP-provided IP is not visible on the public Internet.  CGN may be implemented due to scarcity of IPv4 addresses and not specifically implemented to prevent you from hosting a website, though it will prevent you from hosting a website in a standard manner as a side effect.

As far as why hosting a website is treated specially, due to the way many people expect a website to work, you need a lot of bandwidth (and other infrastructure such as CDNs and load-balanced servers working together) if it's going to be used regularly by more than tens of people, depending on the content.  A major obstacle to that bandwidth is the fact that most residential ISP connections are *asymmetric*, typically meaning you have less incoming bandwidth than outgoing bandwidth.

So this typically falls into ISPs commercial offerings, which are much more expensive and also might offer symmetric bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your service provider "isn't letting you"? Have you contacted them to confirm this?

Your router probably is allowing Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) to open ports to allow you to seed.

You have to manually open the router configuration and "port forward". That is, if your ISP hasn't otherwise locked you out of the router.